# Restrict Users from Programmatically posting form data

Tags: forms, asp.net-4.0

I have a very old ASP.net Application with a Web Form with 1 Dropdown Box and 2 Text Boxes and a Submit Button. 
All 3 are mandatory fields. Based on the data entered, once the user clicks Submit Button additional details are shown on the next page from the database.

On Submit data is posted via Query String that looks like 
http://myserver/myapp/search.aspx?f1=1&f2=tom&f3=sales

Though the application is doing what is supposed to do, off late we came across lot of issues:

As couple of entities  that are interested in our data wrote programs to programatically build the querystrings and hitting our server. 
This is slowing down the server and regular users who manually search records are facing lot of slowness.

Due to come legal restrictions we couldn't implement CAPTCHA or have users get authenticated.

I would appreciate if you can let me know if any of you have come across this kinda situation and how you have dealt with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what legal restrictions are stopping you from using a Captcha???

Answer (score 1):

You could implement source-based rate limiting. I.e. per IP address only allow so many requests per minute. If the requester makes too many requests you simply reject the requests. You could also blacklist the IP addresses that are hitting your app too aggressively. Both of these policies can be enforced by a load balancer like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html).